# Pthreads cast void * argument into int array

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, pthreads

I'm dealing with this code written in c++:

```
int *V;
V = new int[nfilas*ncols];
iret=pthread_create(&threadList[i], NULL, worker_function, (void*)(&V)[nfilas*ncols]);
```

that passes "V" (a int array) to this function:

```
    int *matrix=(int*)ptr;
    for( int r=0; r<nfilas; ++r ){
    for( int c=0; c<ncols; c++ ){
        printf("%d ", matrix[r*ncols+c]);
    }
```

My problem is that i can't convert that void pointer into an array of int elements. How can i solve this? I've try many thing but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance

Comment: You might try just sending `V`. throw out the rest of the casts.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Works in C, but not C++.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Since *when*?? [See it live](http://ideone.com/LsekM2). Do you mean the sender-side or the receiver side? (I *think* you meant on the receiver side, in which case, sure, thats correct; the sender should be fine sans-casts and I should clarify that).

Comment: @DietrichEpp what flags would I have to use in g++ to make it not work?

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, I'm talking about the receiver side.  No automatic casting from `void *` is one of the most noticeable things that makes C++ different from C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely cast from `int *` to `void *` and back...

```
int *V;
V = new int[nfilas*ncols];
iret = pthread_create(
    &threadList[i], NULL, worker_function, static_cast<void *>(V));
```

In your function...

```
int *matrix = static_cast<int *>(ptr);
for(int r = 0; r < nfilas; r++){
    for(int c = 0; c < ncols; c++){
        printf("%d ", matrix[r*ncols+c]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got too much going on in your cast…

Spawn your thread with `pthread_create(..., V); // V is already a pointer`

Comment: mah is correct, but I believe you need an explicit cast to int* from void* inside of your thread.